# Set default parameter when creating user Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When creating a new user in Laravel I want the 'name' attribute to default to something like 'kevin.' I feel like this should be really easy but I've tried many different things and nothing seems to work. This the method I use to create a new user after submitting the form:

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::only('username', 'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation');

    $this->registrationForm->validate($input);

    $user = User::create($input);


    Auth::login($user);

    return Redirect::home();
}
```

I feel like I should be able to simply add `$user->name = "kevin"` after initializing the user, but while it doesn't return an error, there is absolutely nothing under 'name' in the database.

I know this seems stupid, I changed somethings because it wouldn't make sense out of context of the project. Any help is appreciated, let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Are you referring to `username`?

Comment: No. I'm using 'name' as an example. You can see `username` being assigned with `$input`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `$user->save()` after `$user->name = "kevin"`